# Understanding TensorBoard visualization for Siamese architecture

Tags: keras, lstm, tensorboard

I am using a Siamese architecture in my model for a classification task of whether both the inputs are similar.

```
in1 = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='in1')
x1 = Embedding(output_dim=dim, input_dim=n_symbols, input_length=None, 
               weights=[embedding_weights], name='x1')(in1)

in2 = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='in2')
x2 = Embedding(output_dim=dim, input_dim=n_symbols, input_length=None, 
               weights=[embedding_weights], name='x2')(in2)

l = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False))
y1 = l(x1)
y2 = l(x2)

y = concatenate([y1, y2])
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)
model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=[out])
```

It works correctly as the number of weights to be trained remain the same even when I use a single input. The thing that confused my though, was the tensorboard vizualization of the model.

[tensorboard graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx3g1.png)

Shouldn't both `x1` and `x2` map to the same bidirectional node?
Also, what do the 18 and 32 tensors signify?